# Can the VS2010 JumpList be customized

Tags: visual-studio-2010, jump-list

So I love to pin projects to the VS2010 jumplist . . . right click and load.

However, for a couple projects, I'm working on several versions at once.  Foo.sln appears in the list several times . . . once for each release.  If I hover over a given item, I can see the full path, but that takes time to find the version I want . . . I'd like to show the version in the name.

I want to customize this to Foo2.6, Foo2.7, etc . . . I first tried to play with the properties of the jumplist item, but this actually renames the file.  Then I thought perhaps I could do this with links or some other trick . . . while links WORK, they then appear in the jumplist not as the link name, but instead as the solution file name so no benefit.

I could copy the solution file, but what if the solution file changes in source control . . . then the file and the copy are out of sync.

Links are "almost there" . . . does anyone have a cleaver way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JumplistLauncher is quite handy for this. I have pinned it to the taskbar and changed the icon to be Visual Studio's icon. Works great!

http://en.www.ali.dj/jumplist-launcher/

Comment: Funny I already have this utility installed and use it for other things.  I guess I was hoping to keep the DevStudio stuff on the DevStudio ICON, but you're right . . . JumplistLauncher will work here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but you can add shortcuts to your Favorites folder.